# Is is true that for all $n\in\mathbb{N}$ that $\prod\limits_{i=1}^{n}(a+i) \equiv 0 \ [n!]$?

Tags: elementary-number-theory, proof-writing, modular-arithmetic, arithmetic

Let $a\in \mathbb{Z}$, we want to prove that for all $n\in\mathbb{N}$ that $\prod\limits_{i=1}^{n}(a+i) \equiv 0 \ [n!]$ ?

By induction :

For $n=1$ we obtain that $1!$ divides $a+1$.

For $n=2$ we obtain that $2!$ divides $(a+1)(a+2)$ because one term is necessary even.

For the case $n+1$ I need a hint.

Thanks in advance !

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Note that at least for $a\in\Bbb N$, we have that  ${a+n\choose a}$ is an integer. This can be extended to $a\in \Bbb Z$.

Comment: It means that $\frac{(a+n)...(a+1)}{n!}$ is an integer right. So by re-writing for $n+1$ we obtain $\binom{a+n+1}{a}$ ?

Comment: This is certainly true, but it doesn't really help the situation unless one proves either (a) that the definition ${n\choose k}=\frac{n!}{k!(n-k)!}$ gives an integer - which is basically circular from the original problem - or that the various definitions of the binomial (e.g. via recurrence relation and explicit formula) are equivalent.

Comment: @StevenStadnicki what do you mean by "unless one proves either (a)" ?

Comment: @Maman There was a (b) on the second half of that (about various definitions of the binomial) that I accidentally left out, mea culpa.

Comment: @StevenStadnicki ok but the hint of the answer enables to conclude for this exercice ?

Comment: @Maman How do you _know_ that ${a+n\choose a}$ (as defined by $\frac{(a+n)!}{a!n!}$) is an integer?

Comment: @StevenStadnicki I admit that fact. Indeed you choose $a$ among $a+n$ so the result is an integer. Or we can do an induction (with pascal formula maybe).